# Boots Strap fa fa icon

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using this boots strap template *http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/stylish-portfolio/*

At the bottom of the index.html, their is a few fa fa icons.  A facebook,twitter and dribbble.  Right now they are a light blue color. But how can i change that? I want the icons to be different color

I have checked out the css, i can't find anything over the `fa fa icons`, `facebook`,`twitter`, `dribble`, `ul`, `li`.

Where else would it be.
This is the html

```
<ul class="list-inline">
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Those are [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) icons and are rendered essentially as text, so any styling you can perform on text, you can perform on these icons.

That means you can apply a `color` CSS style to the `<i>` tag and the icon will be rendered in that color.

Eg.

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw fa-3x" style="color:blue;"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-3x"  style="color:red;"></i></a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70b2uuLj/)

On a side note, do be aware that most brands such a Facebook, Twitter, YouTube etc have very strict guidelines around how their branding, icons and colors can be used. So you need to be aware of any legal implications if you are changing the colors of their icons.

Answer (score 1):

You can individually target the icon classes and then apply styling to each of them.

```
i.fa-facebook{
  color:red;
}

i.fa-twitter{
  color:green;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpgw3ssd/)

As @steve above says, you should be aware of the restrictions that these companys put on use of their brand assests. The Facebook brand guidelines can be found here; https://www.facebookbrand.com/

You can easily find the others with a simple search in Google for something like "twitter brand guidelines"